the ideal $〈6〉$ in the ring $(\mathbb Z,+,.)$
I am trying to solve this past exam question:
In the ring $(\mathbb Z,+,.)$, the ideal $〈6〉$ is
(a) maximal
(b) prime
(c) strongly prime
(d) another answer.
Which option is correct?
The only theorem I found which may help is

A principal ideal is maximal if and only if the element generating it is irreducible.

However, I am not sure how to check whether $6$ is irreducible or not.


An element $c$ of $R$ is irreducible provided that $(i):$ $c$ is a nonzero nonunit.
$(ii):$ $c=ab \implies a$ or $b$ is a unit.

Here $6=2\times3$ and both $2$ and $3$ are non-unit (i.e. not invertible), so $6$ is reducible.
Also, notice that $\langle 6\rangle\subset \langle 2\rangle$.

An ideal $M$ is said to be maximal if $M \neq R$ and for every ideal $N$ s.t. $M \subset N$, either $M=N$ or $M=R$.

Edit: In PID, irreducible elements are equivalent to prime elements. Since $6$ is not irreducible, it is not prime, the ideal generated by $6$ is not a prime ideal, thus also not strongly prime.

so what is the correct answer?

@gbd I provided two answers, both of them show that it is not maximal.

I mean if it is not maximal then is it  (b) prime or (c) strongly prime or (d) another answer?

@gbd Prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $$, where $p$ is a prime, so not prime, also not strongly prime.

is every strongly prime ideal a prime ideal?

@gbd See this

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)

@BillDubuque OK. Won't happen next time.
